# Facebook comments and moderation tool "Sorry, something went wrong."

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-comments

It's been like 3 days with this eerror which I thought was from fb's side. I had already a working comment box, but 3 days ago it started to show:
Sorry, something went wrong.

We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
Going to the moderation tool page shows the same too http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments .
Curiously though, my comment boxes in other pages are working as supposed to. The affected page is just a personal one of mine: http://efaj.tumblr.com/

From what I've searched, I've only found either old information or unrelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a known new issue with Tumblr and Facebook,

I created a bug report about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134909119955013) and if you want then you can subscribe to it.

Comment: Tumblr problems with Facebook are now fixed, thanks to Eugene Zarakhovsky, if you still got any issues then please report about them in the main bug report here:
[http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134909119955013](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/134909119955013)
You are welcome to check my demo blog: [http://gil-goldshlager.tumblr.com/](http://gil-goldshlager.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browsers cookies. That will fix it.